# Twitter bootstrap modal loads wrong remote data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap modal featurs and loading data from remote locations. I'm providing the remote url for a set of thumbnails with the hope that once the thumbnail is clicked, the appropriate data (a large version of the image) is displayed. I'm using the html declarative style to define the remote urls and all the features of the modal.

What I find is that Twitter bootstrap modal loads first remote url then does not display subsequent remote data, (although a request to the proper url is made in Chrome) but displays first loaded data always. How do I get it to show the proper data?

View:

```
#gallery-navigation
  %ul
    - @profile.background_images.each do |image|
      %li
        = link_to image_tag(image.background_image.url(:thumb)), remote_image_path(image.id), :role => "button", :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#image-modal", :remote => remote_image_path(image.id)}

/ Modal
#image-modal.modal.hide.fade(role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true")
  .modal-body
```

Controller:

```
  def remote_image
    @image = current_user.profile.background_images.find(params[:image_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        render :partial => "remote_image", :locals => { :image => @image }
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: The remote loading is only done in the [*constructor* (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L33). And there is only one constructor call per modal in its normal use.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected... too bad, should be able to be smart enough to see that if remote data is different, it should load the indicated data IMHO.

Comment: The remote option is more like an extra, non-essential-at-all, not even related to modal option. You could easily do the same thing with your own data attribute. Are you interested in that alternative ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I figured out an alternative, just peeved that I wasted so much time assuming this type of thing was easily done with bootstrap modals

Comment: It's as easily done with jQuery. You should post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I would rather accept your first comment as an answer, as it's more accurate to the question :), please submit it and I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plugin doesn't actually load the wrong data, it only loads the first call. Why ?

Because the remote loading is only done in the constructor of the plugin : [constructor source on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L33)

And there is only one call to the constructor per modal (in its normal behavior) : [singleton source on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L204)

---

IMHO, the remote option is more like an extra, *non-essential-at-all*, *not-even-related-to-the-modal-plugin* option. It can be very useful though.

And it's very easy to reproduce the same behavior with very little code, and as much remote loading as we want : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ThLYb/)

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="/some.url" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body" href="#myModal" class="btn">Btn 1</a>
```

```js
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if(remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried multiple solutions to get remote urls to work, all for naught. Your solution is THE ONLY ONE THAT WORKED!